# Error while implementing multi-tab inheritance in django

Tags: django-models

I create fllowing multiple inheritance in model.py, while running python manage.py makemigrations getting the error
Error :- ERRORS:
polls.VideoWithThumbnail: (models.E005) The field 'media_ptr' from parent model 'polls.video' clashes with the field 'media_ptr' from parent model 'polls.photo'.

```
class Media(models.Model):    
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField()


class Photo(Media):    
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='photo')


class Video(Media):    
    videos=models.FileField(upload_to='videos')


class VideoWithThumbnail(Video,Photo):    
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
class Media(models.Model):    
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

class Photo(Media):
    photo_to_media = models.OneToOneField(Media, parent_link=True)
    is_faculty = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Video(Media):
    video_to_media = models.OneToOneField(Media, parent_link=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class VideoWithThumbnail(Video,Photo):    
    pass
```